# How do I insert a comma into text files of a directory?

Tags: python, regex, file, overwrite

I have a bunch of text files in a directory and need to replace the text in them. Each line looks like this:

```
B6  0x040A43
B17  0x6C00C8
```

I need to:

1. Replace the first part with `1,28`.
2. Delete space, which is a `\t` white space.
3. Delete the hex identifier `0x`.
4. Add a comma after the next two characters.

So the result should look like this:

```
1,28,04,0A43
1,28,6C,00C8
```

I'm still learning python and regex and after a few hours of playing around this and so far I've written the following:

```py
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, '*.txt')):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines()
        for line in lines:
            line = re.sub(r'B\d{1,}[\s+]0x','1,28,', line)
            print(line)
```

This prints out `1,28,040A43` so it has everything but the last comma.

My questions are:

1. How can I insert the comma into the string?
2. Is this the best way to replace the text in my files
   or should I be accessing it in a different way?

Comment: Strings are not lists, but both are sequences and iterables.

Comment: Are all your lines going to look like that or you need to find them first?

Comment: Because if all your line going to look like that you can just do line = "1,28," + line[-6:-4] + "," + line[-4:] . With that, there isn't a need for regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
import os
import re
directory = 'test'
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, '*.txt')):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines()
        for line in lines:
            line = re.sub(r'B\d{1,}[\s+]0x','1,28,', line)
            line = line[:7] + ',' + line[7:]
            print(line)
```

Output

> 1,28,04,0A43
>   1,28,6C,00C8

Comment: Thanks so much! I forgot you could do that with strings